# Space in mutiple level Master-detail in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I have a grid which has 5 level hierarchy(Master-detail) .So when i expand to 5  the level grid,it's height becomes so small and scroll bar comes in.Is there any way to show child grid take full height and hide the parent according?

Comment: It would be nice if you will provide your code or place your code into JSFiddle and share link here.

Comment: Jayesh, i got the solution.if i change Scrollable() to Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Enabled(false)) in child grids,the child girds are expanding to show all the rows according to the paging.